# Technique to control the quantity of products

Tags: c#, mysql, billing

I'm working on c# application that used for Drugstore (buying,selling drugs).
I want to ask, is there a formal way to control the quantity ?! i mean .. When i press on sell button, what is the operations on quantity that should happen ?

this is what i did:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into bills (bill_Number,bill_Date,bill_From,bill_Note,bill_TaxRate,bill_DisRate,bill_EntryDate,cus_Sup,byUser) values(" + txbBillNumber.Text + ",'" + DateTime.Parse(txbBillDate.Text).Year + "-" + DateTime.Parse(txbBillDate.Text).Month + "-" + DateTime.Parse(txbBillDate.Text).Day + "'," + sup_Id + ",'" + txb_Note.Text + "'," + taxRate + "," + disRate + ",'" + DateTime.Now.Year + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "'," + cus_Sup + ",'" + users + " | " + Environment.MachineName.ToString() + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + " | " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() + "')", objConn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//get the ID
cmd = new MySqlCommand("select max(bill_Id) from bills", objConn);
MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dataReader.Read();
billID = int.Parse(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
dataReader.Close();


//insert into Bill_Details
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{

    cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into bill_Details (bill_Id,prod_Id,de_Cost,de_Quantity,de_Bonus,de_Price,de_ExpireDate,de_DisRate) values(" + billID + "," + int.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text) + "," + decimal.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text) + "," + decimal.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text) + "," + decimal.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text) + "," + decimal.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text) + ",'" + DateTime.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text).Year + "-" + DateTime.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text).Month + "-" + DateTime.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[7].Text).Day + "'," + decimal.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[10].Text) +")", objConn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

//Edit information in products table IN ADDING
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
        cmd = new MySqlCommand("update products set prod_Quantity = (prod_Quantity-"+ ( decimal.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text)+decimal.Parse(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text) ) +") where prod_Id=" + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text, objConn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or can you help me with a link that could be useful to me ?

Comment: **warning** your code has *sql injection* attack points.

Comment: When you sell an item, do you end up with more or less of that item? Is the change in your inventory dependent on how many you sell?

Comment: @TZHX , yes it depend on !

Comment: @DanielA.White , What you meant ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost - please take note of the comment about SQL injection. If your concern is about design patterns, the first pattern you need to be concerned with is a correctly parameterized sql command in ADO.net

See this example:

```
            //create the command
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(
                    "SELECT value1, value2 FROM myTable WHERE id_Field = @_id", 
                    connection); 

            //add the parameter to the command, with the desired value            
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_id", myTextBox.Text);
```

Secondly, to answer your question, there is no specific pattern that applies to all cases. However I would recommend a simple Data Access class to represent your inventory items (medicine) and this class should have a generic addInventory(int adder) method. A sale would result in passing a negative number to the add inventory method, which would then decrement the inventory. Thus a sale would be executed as:

```
     var myMedicine = new Medicine();
     //sell 10 units
     myMedicine.addInventory(-10);
```

Alternatively, if other work needs to be done during a sale besides decrementing inventory, its likely that the addInventory method should be private and called internally from a public .Sold(int unitsSold) method which contains the additional work as well.